# (Doctrine ORM) How to order SELECT by many-to-one relationship

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I have a database with *types* and *categories* (among other, unrelated things). *Types* have a many-to-one relationship with *categories*. What I want is to select all type rows, ordered first by category name and then by type weight and lastly by type name (all ascending). The critical part is that I want all the types with the same category to be grouped together in the result. Being the SQL neophyte that I am, I thought a simple join statement followed by appropriate order by statements would be sufficient. I was wrong. The result I'm getting makes no sense to me.

Actual result (type name - category name):

1. Aircraft Landing Strut - **Aircraft**
2. Aicraft Rotor Blade - **Aircraft**
3. Aircraft Wing - **Aircraft**
4. Bicycle Frame - **Riding Cycles**
5. Boat Bow - **Watercraft**
6. Boat Cargo Deck - **Watercraft**
7. Boulder Bottom - **Rocks**
8. Boulder Top - **Rocks**
9. Bowed Element - **Others**
10. Brick 1x1 w/Juice Carton Print - **Bricks Printed**
11. Brick 1x1 w/Milk Carton Print - **Bricks Printed**
12. Car Wash Brush Holder - **Others**
13. [etc.]

Expected result (type name - category name):

1. Aircraft Landing Strut - **Aircraft**
2. Aicraft Rotor Blade - **Aircraft**
3. Aircraft Wing - **Aircraft**
4. Brick 1x1 w/Juice Carton Print - **Bricks Printed**
5. Brick 1x1 w/Milk Carton Print - **Bricks Printed**
6. Bowed Element - **Others**
7. Car Wash Brush Holder - **Others**
8. Bicycle Frame - **Riding Cycles**
9. Boulder Bottom - **Rocks**
10. Boulder Top - **Rocks**
11. Boat Bow - **Watercraft**
12. Boat Cargo Deck - **Watercraft**
13. [etc.]

There are over 2,000 type rows, so the above lists are obviously very truncated. There are no errors. It's probably also important that the results are paginated (which has been working perfectly).

I'm using Doctrine 2.5.x with my own content management system. In the repository for the type entity I'm using `QueryBuilder` to construct the query as follows (the max result is a global setting and the first result is calculated outside the repository based on the current page number):

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('t');

$qb->select('t, c'); // omitting this does not change the result
$qb->join('t.category', 'c');
$qb->addOrderBy('c.name', 'ASC'); // this does not work as expected
$qb->addOrderBy('t.weight', 'ASC');
$qb->addOrderBy('t.name', 'ASC');
$qb->setMaxResults(20);
$qb->setFirstResult(0);

return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

The resultant SQL statement is as follows:

```
SELECT b0_.ID AS ID_0, b0_.weight AS weight_1, b0_.name AS name_2, b0_.number AS number_3, b0_.name_alt AS name_alt_4, b0_.note AS note_5, b1_.ID AS ID_12, b1_.slug AS slug_13, b1_.name AS name_14, b1_.`desc` AS desc_15, b0_.cat_id AS cat_id_16 FROM types b0_ INNER JOIN categories b1_ ON b0_.cat_id = b1_.ID ORDER BY b1_.name ASC, b0_.weight ASC, b0_.name ASC LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

The type entity is set up like this (with irrelevant fields ommitted):

```
/**
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="Nevermind\Repository\TypeRepository")
 * @Table(name="types", options={"collate"="utf8mb4_unicode_ci", "charset"="utf8mb4"})
 */
class Type {

    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer", name="ID")
     * @GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="types", fetch="EAGER")
     * @JoinColumn(name="cat_id", referencedColumnName="ID")
     */
    protected $category;

    /**
     * @Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $weight = 0;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", unique=true)
     */
    protected $name = '';

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", unique=true, length=12)
     */
    protected $number = '';

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $name_alt;

    /**
     * @Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $note;

}
```

And the category entity is set up like this:

```
/**
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="Nevermind\Repository\DefaultRepository")
 * @Table(name="categories", options={"collate"="utf8mb4_unicode_ci", "charset"="utf8mb4"})
 */
class Category {

    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer", name="ID")
     * @GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", unique=true)
     */
    protected $slug = '';

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @Column(type="text", name="`desc`", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $desc;

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Type", mappedBy="category", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @OrderBy({"weight"="ASC", "name"="ASC"})
     */
    protected $types;

}
```

`TypeRepository` extends `DefaultRepository` which extends Doctrine's `EntityRepository`.

Comment: For debugging, I would `echo $qb->getSqlQuery();` to see the actual SQL statement being sent to MySQL server, and test that. That would help us determine the cause of the unexpected behavior... is it a problem in the SQL query text, or is it a problem in the handling of the return.

Comment: Done, though I had to use $qb->getQuery()->getSQL() as $qb->getSqlQuery() gives me a non-existent method error.

Comment: I put the SQL directly into phpMyAdmin and it appears to be exactly the same result I'm getting in the HTML for my CMS (including for subsequent pages if I change the OFFSET number)

Comment: Please edit the question to include the first few rows of the output from the SQL statement when run in phpMyAdmin, i.e. including all the columns, and also to include the first few rows of the types and categories tables. Thanks.

Comment: Forgive me, but that seems like a lot to ask (especially since my question is already super long), so could you help me understand what might be gained from having all this extraneous information? I was hoping that this would be a relatively common sort of select statement that a typical, skilled SQL developer would know, rather than being a bug hunt.

Comment: I did the best experiment I could using your sql statement and a few rows of data, and the sort came out correct. So I wondered if the data was somehow the problem, and therefore wanted to look at your actual rows. One row of each table would do, I guess. This isn't a run of the mill sql problem at all (as you can tell from the number of upvotes on the question).

Comment: Can you try `$q = $qb->getQuery();
$q->setHint(Query::HINT_REFRESH, true);` ? Do you query any types before this querybuilder code?

Comment: @MandyShaw You were right - it was the actual data. I completely forgot that I'd changed the category name (when displayed) to be derived either from the name column OR (if the name column is NULL) transformed from the slug column. _Changing the query to use `category.slug` instead therefore fixes the issue_, because the slug column is never NULL. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Please put the solution into an answer and accept it, so that future enquirers are clear what happened (comments may disappear over time, and also this question will still be coming up as unanswered - putting 'solved' in the title is not normal practice on SO). Thanks.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I guess you can tell that I'm new here :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The weird ordering of the result was caused by the fact that the category `name` column is sometimes `null` (when displayed the name falls back to the transformed contents of the `slug` column, a change I'd completely forgotten about). Therefore simply changing the first order-by statement to be `c.slug` instead solves the problem. D'oh!

So remember, ordering by columns which can be null will cause strange results!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried

```
$qb->select('t, c');
...
$qb->orderBy('c.name', 'ASC'); // orderBy not addOrderBy for the first clause
$qb->addOrderBy('t.weight', 'ASC');
$qb->addOrderBy('t.name', 'ASC');
...
```

Comment: I have - did not change the output.